# Akka Stream: one Source.actorRef, two Flow with filter, just one Actor as Source

Tags: scala, playframework, stream, akka

I would like to have two stream, just one source (Source.actorRef) but filtered twice... I don't know how to do that I have this:

```
val streams = Source.actorRef[JsValue](0, dropHead)
val sink = system.actorOf(Props[SinkActor], name = "sink")

val srcRef = Flow[JsValue]
.to(Sink.actorRef(sink,"Completed"))
.runWith(streams)
```

I tried two Sink with runWith but that would generate actorrefs so two actors are created as well.. or that I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use broadcast to have two separate streams from one source and next filter them independently.

More details about broadcast in docs - http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/scala/stream-graphs.html

Comment: Thx, but aren't there a way to use broadcast or similar without flowgraph/dsl?

Comment: Flow is about one in and one out. To build more complex flows use graphs API

Comment: You can use broadcast without the dsl by running your source as a publisher with fanout = true. i.e.  source.runWith(Sink.publisher(true))